# Is there something wrong with the coding for superscript?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Superscript used to be...well...superscript. Now, it seems that characters enclosed in `<sup></sup>` no longer appear in a superscript position. Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Confirmed: shrunk numbers sitting on the line. Especially a shame for answers [like this one](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/16995/2215) which use notation conventions. Looks like it's network wide: it was [reported on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296134/203418) seven hours ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Now fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296182/203418).

[image: thumbs up]